# Why do so many posts use the term 'in doubt' or 'have a doubt' regarding established physics?

Tags: discussion

An oddly large number of articles are titles with, or include in their opening line, a phrase like '*I have a doubt regarding gravity*'; see the articles at the bottom, for examples.

In most cases, it doesn't seem that the OP actually '*doubts*' that the physics in question are true.  Instead, they seem to mean that they are generally *confused*.

Is there a particular language which this usage transliterates from?  Possibly a particular thesaurus entry leading people astray?

[Intuition behind Work](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/58148/intuition-behind-work)
[Electric Field Lines for Continuous Distribution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57907/electric-field-lines-for-continuous-distribution)
[Doubt in Kinematics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57436/doubt-in-kinematics)
[Is propagation of uncertainties linear?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59628/why-propagation-of-uncertainty-is-linear)

---

Edit:  See also (thanks to @Yrogirg)
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/what-exactly-might-non-native-speakers-mean-by-doubt

Comment: @user16307 is there *any* purpose to either of your comments?

Comment: see also the same topic at MSE http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/what-exactly-might-non-native-speakers-mean-by-doubt

Comment: @Yrogirg thanks!  That thread has lots of good material on it

Comment: Dear zhermes, you may have listed 4 examples of questions, but they were posted by the same user, user162..., which diminishes your suggestions that it's a common phenomenon.

Comment: @LubošMotl Here's an OP 'doubting' mathematics: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60524/implicit-differentiation-a-doubt

Comment: @LubošMotl ha, that's very interesting - I completely didn't notice that; but, as the meta.math article reaffirms (along with the responses to this post), I'm confident it is a fairly common occurrence.

Comment: Better link at English.SE: [Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a phrase, common to Indian English (and some other Asian dialects), that means "I am confused". The word "doubt" is used as a noun here to mean "a confusion" or "an issue" or "a question".

It's fine if you edit this out, just don't proactively go looking for this to take it out.

Comment: Exactly! I learned to disengage from saying "I have a doubt" once I moved out of India because it is rather strange outside the confines of Indian english!

Comment: @drN: It's the opposite for me; I moved _to_ India from the States and these phrases are jarring to my ears :P

Comment: Well you'll get used to it. Its not so bad really. I take you teach then?

Comment: @drN: Me? Teach? _chuckles_ . No, I'm a first year student of engineering physics :)

Comment: Well, try not to have any *doubts* then! `:P`

Comment: Actually... *I've got a doubt now..!* - Should I get rid of these doubts..? ;-)

Comment: This is hilarious. I have used the phrase "I have a doubt" millions of times.

Comment: Judging from the usage I see on Stack Exchange, you can usually just replace "doubt" with "question" and it will make a lot more sense to US English speakers.

Comment: @Manishearth It's also Italian by the way (and possibly other european languages). :P

Answer (score 9):

The best synonym for this use of "doubt", common in the Indian sub-continent, in British / American English is "question": - "I have a doubt" is equivalent to "I have a question". As such, it's padding, and should be edited out of questions, as part of a more substantial edit that removes chatty stuff.